# R error in using read.delim to read Chinese character files in utf-8 encoding

Tags: r, utf-8, chinese-locale

I have a utf-8 encoded file test.txt, where the values are delimiter separated

```
a   b   c
小   小   大
小   大   小
大   小   小
```

And I read to read the data using the commands

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Chinese")
data <- read.delim("test.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
```

But data is read as a data frame with output

```
[1] X.U.FEFF.a b          c         
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

My system is windows 7

How to read the data correctly?

Comment: You might try fileEncoding not encoding

Answer (score 2):

I just tried `read.csv` and it works fine. I tested your code, the `read.delim` works out of box, too.

```
> a <- read.csv('/tmp/test.txt', sep="\t", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(a)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr  "小" "小" "大"
 $ b: chr  "小" "大" "小"
 $ c: chr  "大" "小" "小"
> a
   a  b  c
1 小 小 大
2 小 大 小
3 大 小 小

> data <- read.delim("/tmp/test.txt", encoding="utf-8")
> data
   a  b  c
1 小 小 大
2 小 大 小
3 大 小 小
```

Then I tried your `Sys.setlocale` command, and it didn't work for me, which indicates the command itself is invalid after I tested set the locale to German.

```
# ?Sys.setlocale:
# "Attempts to set an invalid locale are ignored. There may or may not be a warning, depending on the OS."
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Chinese")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Chinese") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "Chinese" cannot be honored
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")  # Mac OS X, in UTF-8
[1] "de_DE"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/de_DE/en_US.UTF-8"
```

To successfully set the locale to Chinese, you can try this([Cited From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228727/input-chinese-characters-not-correctly-echoed-in-ess)):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","zh_CN.utf-8")
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "zh_CN.utf-8/zh_CN.utf-8/zh_CN.utf-8/C/zh_CN.utf-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: I am using windows 7. and Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","zh_CN.utf-8") gives me the message 
  
    Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "zh_CN.utf-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "zh_CN.utf-8" cannot be honored

I think windows 7 has problem in reading chinese characters

Comment: Chinese is a windows locale, your answer gives a Linux locale

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, and neither "chinese", "Chinese" or "zh_CN.utf-8" worked. All give 'OS reports request to set locale to "..." cannot be honored'